# Tableau HTML embed not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, embed, tableau-api

I've embedded 2 Tableau dashboards into an internal website that my company uses.  I was able to view them in Chrome when I added them 2 days ago.  However, now only a blank space shows on the page where they used to be.  I can still view the embedded dashboards if I open the page using Internet Explorer 8.

Do you have any ideas for why my embed code stopped working?

I've deleted all cookies/browser history.  I am able to access the dashboards directly (so it doesn't seem to be a permissioning issue.)

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='***TABLEAUWORKBOOKURL***'></script>
<div class='tableauPlaceholder' style='width: 1004px; height: 862px;'>
 <object class='tableauViz' width='1004' height='862' style='display:none;'>
  <param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2Ftableau.***COMPANYNAME***.org%2F' />
  <param name='site_root' value='&#47;t&#47;Sandbox' />
  <param name='name' value='***WORKBOOKNAME***' />
  <param name='tabs' value='yes' />
  <param name='toolbar' value='yes' />
 </object>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at the browser console window to see if there are any error messages.  Also, note that the script src tag should reference the Tableau javascript file (not the workbook url).

Comment: thank you!  Weirdly, it's now working again.... though I didn't do anything.  This is really good troubleshooting advice if it happens again tho, esp since it's public-facing (well, it faces more than just my department).(And yes... I didn't mean URL... I'm pretty unfamiliar with this, so thank you for explaining what that part is actually doing.)

Comment: One more thing: as much as I love StackOverflow, the [Tableau community forums](http://community.tableausoftware.com/community/forums) are a better place to get Tableau questions answered.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>          
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-bootstrap/0.5pre/assets/js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://public.tableausoftware.com/javascripts/api/tableau_v8.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function initializeViz() {
                 var placeholderDiv = document.getElementById("tableauViz");
                 var url = "http://public.tableausoftware.com/views/WorldIndicators/GDPpercapita";
                 var options = {
                    width: placeholderDiv.offsetWidth,
                    height: placeholderDiv.offsetHeight,
                    hideTabs: true,
                    hideToolbar: true,
                    onFirstInteractive: function () {
                      workbook = viz.getWorkbook();
                      activeSheet = workbook.getActiveSheet();
                    }
                  };
                  viz = new tableauSoftware.Viz(placeholderDiv, url, options);
                  }


function filterSingleValue() {
  activeSheet.applyFilterAsync(
    "Region",
    "The Americas",
    tableauSoftware.FilterUpdateType.REPLACE);
}

                function clearFilters() {
  activeSheet.clearFilterAsync("Region");
  activeSheet.clearFilterAsync("F: GDP per capita (curr $)");
}
            </script>
            <style>
                #tableauViz
                {
                    height: 800px;
                    width: max-content;
                }
            </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tableauViz">
                  <p>
                    <button onclick="$(initializeViz);">Run this code</button>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <button onclick="$(filterSingleValue);">Filter View</button>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <button onclick="$(clearFilters);">Load Default</button>
                  </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have created a div with id as tableauViz and i am mapping the tableau workbook and its required parameters to load the initial viz using javascript.

This method works fine for me.